# Writing an algorithm to calculate the convergency criteria for Gauss' Method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to write an algorithm that would calculate the convergence criteria for a given linear system, but I am facing some sort of semantic error. Then, I am being unable to make any advance because I don't have much knowledge of JavaScript.

The code is as you can see below:

```
var SumOfLines=function(A,B,X)
{
   var N;
   var I=[];
   for(var i=0;i<A.length;++i)
   {
      for(var j=0;j<A.length;++j)
      {
         if (i!=j)
         {
            N+=Math.abs(A[i][j])
         }
         else
         {
            N=N
         }
      I[i] = N/Math.abs(A[i][i])
      }
   }
      return I[i]
}

var A=[[10,2,1]
      ,[1,5,1]
      ,[10,3,10]]

var B=[7,-5,-3]

text=SumOfLines(A,B,[1,2,3])
```

Basically, it will calculate for each line of the linear system the result of the sum of all the coefficients' modulus except for the one in the diagonal divided by the modulus of the element of the diagonal.

After compiling and running the code, the result that I get is `'undefined'`. Does anybody know what could be causing that error message? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need two additional arguments `B, X`?

Comment: Cool kids do like this `function sumOfLines(A) {
   return A.map(function(row, i){
      return row.reduce(function(sum, val, j) {
        return i === j ? sum : (sum + Math.abs(val));
      }, 0)/Math.abs(row[i]);
   });
}`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function, you return I[i]. At this point, i has the value of A.length, so you're returning a non-existing element from your array. if you want to return the last element of the array, just return `I.pop()`

Comment: Returning just I gave me an array of values, which is what I want, but I am getting strange values for the second and third results:

0.3,1,1.8

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript uninitialized variables have undefined as default value.

Try changing this:

```
var N;
```

into this:

```
var N=0;
```

(or any other meaningful initial value)

Other than this, your array is empty(size=0) and you can't add new element with an index, you need to use `push()`, that adds a new element at the end increasing the size of the array.

Change this:

```
I[i] = N/Math.abs(A[i][i])
```

into this:

```
I.push(N/Math.abs(A[i][i]));
```

Update:

I've just noticed, change that return value:

```
return I[i]
```

`i` is undefined there, you are outside the `for`.
Change it to something like `return I[I.length-1]`

Comment: It keeps me with the same `undefined` output. I tried writing just return I and it gave me a vector of results but the calculations for second and third lines are wrong.

Comment: Updated, the return statement cannot work, also, i've see your other comment, remember to initialize N with something.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers, you helped me a lot while fixing the code. You can see it below:

```
var SumOfLines=function(A,B,X)
{
   var N=0;
   var I=[];
   for(var i=0;i<A.length;++i)
   {
      for(var j=0;j<A.length;++j)
      {
         if (i!=j)
         {
            N+=Math.abs(A[i][j])
         }
         else
         {
            N+=0
         }
      I[i] = N/Math.abs(A[i][i])
      }
      N=0
   }
      return I
}

var A=[[10,2,1]
      ,[1,5,1]
      ,[2,3,10]]

var B=[7,-5,-3]

text=SumOfLines(A,B,[1,2,3])
```

Also, the code has to reset the value of N for each one of the iterations, and that was the reason of the code giving me wrong results for the second and third line.